# ДП. Наибольшая квадратная подматрица из единиц

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, математика

Изучаю ДП на классических задачах. Есть такая задача:
**Дана матрица NxM состоящая только из нулей и единиц, нужно найти площадь наибольшей квадратной подматрицы состоящей только из единиц.** 
В гугле нашел формулу:

```
a[i][j] = min (a[i-1][j-1],a[i][j-1],a[i-1][j])+1
```

Но к сожалению, ничего в ней не понимаю. Единственное, что я понимаю, это то что от `a[i-1][j-1]` (`a[i][j]` - сторона квадрата с макс. площадью у которого нижний угол имеет координаты `i,j`) можно перейти к `a[i][j]`, но для этого надо чтоб и элемент был равен 1 и чтобы слева и сверху от элемента `i,j` элементы были равны 1.

Comment: А что такое ДП, простите?

Comment: @VladD судя по задаче, вольное сокращение от "Динамическое Программирование"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Программа на PHP выглядит так:

```
$a = [
    [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0],
    [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1],
    [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],
    [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],
    [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0],
    [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0],
    [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1],
    [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]
];

foreach($a as $str){
    print "<br>";
    foreach($str as $item) print $item;
}
print "<br>";
$m = count($a);
$n = count($a[0]);
$side = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++){
        if ($i*$j == 0) continue;
        if($a[$i][$j] == 1) $a[$i][$j] = min($a[$i][$j-1], $a[$i-1][$j], $a[$i-1][$j-1]) + 1;
        if ($a[$i][$j]>$side) $side=$a[$i][$j];
    }
}
foreach($a as $str){
    print "<br>";
    foreach($str as $item) print $item;
}
printf("<br><br>Площадь максимального квадрата равна %d", $side*$side);
```

Вывод такой:

```
00110011010
00110011011
00111111010
00011111011
00111111010
00011111011
00111111010
00110011010
00110011011
00110011011

00110011010
00120012011
00121112010
00012222011
00112333010
00012344011
00112345010
00120012010
00120012011
00120012012

Площадь максимального квадрата равна 25
```

Нетрудно видеть, что после выполнения программы исходная матрица содержит в качестве элементов максимальную сторону заполненной единицами матрицы с соответствующим нижним правым углом (максимум вычисляется по уже преобразованным элементам матрицы).
Каким образом это происходит?

Для левого столбца и верхней строки эти элементы уже соответствуют, поэтому в обработке они пропущены.

В остальных случах - текущий элемент матрицы увеличивается при условии, что он равен 1. При этом за базу для увеличения принимается минимальный из трёх элементов, граничащих с текущим элементом слева, сверху и слева-сверху.
Несложный анализ картинок показывает, что эта формула верна.

P.S. Проведём этот анализ для следующего текущего состояния матрицы.[image: Square matrix]

При формировании очередного элемента (который пока равен 1) использованы следующие факты:

1. Очередной элемент равен единице (если он был бы нулевым, то и сторона квадрата тоже)
2. Максимальный квадрат слева-сверху от очередного элемента (чёрный квадрат) имеет сторону 3, поэтому максимальная сторона нового квадрата не может быть больше 4. В общем случае это ограничение равно длине стороны чёрного квадрата плюс 1.
3. В условиях п.2 длина заполненной зелёной полоски равна стороне зелёного квадрата и равна 3, поэтому максимальная сторона нового квадрата не может быть больше 4. В общем случае это ограничение равно стороне зелёного квадрата плюс 1.
4. В условиях п.2 длина заполненной красной полоски равна стороне красного квадрата и равна 3, поэтому максимальная сторона нового квадрата не может быть больше 4. В общем случае это ограничение равно стороне красного квадрата плюс 1.
5. Поскольку пп. 1-4 исчерпывают список возможных ограничений, то при выполненном п.1 максимальная длина стороны заполненного квадрата с нижним правым углом на очередном элементе матрицы равна минимуму этой величины по чёрному, зелёному и красному квадратам, увеличенному на единицу.

Answer (score 9):

Ответ содержится в самой формуле. По сути вы преобразуете матрицу, которая содержит только 0 и 1, к матрице, которая содержит длины сторон квадратов.

Правило вычисления:

```
if (a[i][j] != 0)
{
    a[i][j] = min (a[i-1][j-1],a[i][j-1],a[i-1][j])+1
}
```

Из правила видно, что если будет хотя бы один нулевой элемент, то значение элемента не изменится.

Для начала возьмем матрицу 2*2 заполненную только 1 и пройдем по ее ячейкам по приведенному правилу. значения ячеек за пределами матрицы будем считать равными 0. Получаем:
1 1 => 1 1
1 1 => 1 2

не трудно заметить, значение правого нижнего угла матрицы изменилось на 2.

Для матрицы 3*3 преобразование будет выглядеть так:
1 1 1 => 1 1 1
1 1 1 => 1 2 2
1 1 1 => 1 2 3

После преобразования таким образом произвольной прямоугольной матрицы с 0 и 1, решение задачи сводится к поиску максимального элемента в преобразованной матрице.

**Upd.**

По просьбе трудящихся постараюсь показать вывод этой формулы. Сразу предупреждаю, что правильную математическую терминологию я основательно забыл, поэтому "на пальцах".

За основу возьмем утверждение, что элемент матрицы **A** равный 1 является квадратной подматрицей размера 1*1 и все ее элементы отличны от 0. Элемент матрицы равный 0 - является пустой подматрицей, все элементы которой равны 0. Т.к. в обоих случаях подматрицы содержат единственный элемент, оба утверждения верны.

Главная диагональ состоит из элементов a[i][i] (i=1..n)

Условимся что **A'[k][k] = k, если все элементы подматрицы A' размера k отличны от 0**.

И еще одно утверждение: В квадратной матрице размера N можно выделить к квадратную подматрицу размера N-1 четырьмя различными способами (по числу углов).

Из всего выше сказанного следует, что если A[i][j] = k > 0, то в матрице **А** существует квадратная подматрица **A'** размера k, все элементы которой отличны от 0, при этом сам элемент **A[i][j]** является элементом **A'[k][k]** этой подматрицы.

Тогда **k = min(A[i-1][j-1], A[i-1][j], A[i][j-1])** будет означать минимальный размер трех прилегающих к **A[i][j]** квадратных подматриц все элементы которых отличны от 0. Если сам элемент **A[i][j]** отличен от 0, то существует подматрица размера **k+1**, все элементы которой также отличны от 0.

Как-то так. Надеюсь не слишком исковеркал мат.терминологию.

Comment: А как формулу эту все-таки вывести или доказать? Потому что для меня самое главное это то как получили формулу, написать программу не сложно. Почему минимум берем и как задачи a[i][j-1], a[i-1][j] помогают решить задачу a[i][j]?

Comment: @АндрейМоскаленко дополнил